# Commit & Sync directly without a pull request?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, terminal

I have a project on GitHub which I've created from my windows. Now I'm on an ubuntu and I need to get similar access to the repo as I had on windows.

I have git installed through my terminal and I've used `git clone https://github.com/SkamahOne/MyProject` to get the files to my computer.

Now I'd like to commit the made changes and sync them without creating a pull request in the middle; this was possible on windows with the GitHub client GUI, but I don't know how to do it through Terminal with ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

The pull request only creates a highly visible stream of work between you and the repository on GitHub.  If you truly wish to skip that, then you can simply commit and push to the repository as normal.

```
git commit
git push origin master (or whichever branch you're on)
```

If you have write access to the repository, and you're creating a new branch, then you'd use something like:

```
git push -u origin <new-branch-name>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I could just do it this easily :) One more question; how do I add a title and description to the commit via command line?

Comment: Use `git commit -m "A message" `, although I'd encourage you to look up ways to use an editor when committing.  You may have more than a few words to say about a commit.

Comment: More to the point, a pull request is a workflow for getting commits from users without write access into a particular repository.

Comment: That's a good point.  I'll be sure to add that tidbit into the answer.